# Numerically solving the equation of a simple pendulum with Runge-Kutta.

Tags: numerical-methods, elliptic-integrals, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve the equation $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \dfrac{g}{L} \sin{\theta} = 0$ using Runge-Kutta. I have alread split it into the following equations

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{\mathrm{d}t} = - \dfrac{g}{L} \sin{\theta}$

$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t} = \omega$

I have implemented it correctly for the most part however It doesn't appear to care what value of theta I put in initially, the period does work correctly (at least it appears this way) and is dependent on the omega I put in initially. The angle also increases first, ideally I want the first frame to be where the pendulum is at its maximum angle and for it to fall down from there. The maximum angle (no matter what I set it to initially) looks to be around 1 RAD.

I'm only a high school student so I'm a bit lost, I tried to solve the equations analytically at first however I haven't read far into elliptic integrals.

Just a quick note: a ShmpIntance object will be initialised in the main procedure and then a frame and canvas will be created which call the
getGFX method repeatedly where x is incremented each by 1 each cycle. There some code in action behind the scenes making sure there is a maximum of 60 cycles per seconds (60FPS).

```
package sim;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ShmpInstance extends SimInstance {

private double omega, theta, length;
private double currentT, lastT;
private int xPosPix, yPosPix;
private double a, b, c, d, h;

private int lengthInPix, lengthFInPix;

private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

public ShmpInstance(double length, double theta_0, int width, int height) {

    super(width, height);

    this.theta = theta_0;
    this.omega = Math.sqrt(g / length);
    this.length = length;

    if(8*(height/10) > 4*(width/10)){
    lengthInPix = 4*(width/10);
    } else {
    lengthInPix = 8*(height/10);
    }

    if(height > width){ 
        lengthFInPix = 2*(width/25);
    } else {
        lengthFInPix = 2*(height/25);
    } 

}

public Graphics getGFX (Graphics g, int x){

    lastT = currentT;
    currentT = (double)(x) / 60;
    h = (currentT-lastT);

    RungeKutta(theta, omega);

    xPosPix = (int)(width/2 + lengthInPix*Math.sin(theta));
    yPosPix = (int)(height/10 + lengthInPix*Math.cos(theta));

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(xPosPix, yPosPix, xPosPix - (int)(lengthFInPix*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(theta)), yPosPix + (int)(lengthFInPix*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(theta)));
    g.drawLine(xPosPix, yPosPix, xPosPix + (int)(lengthFInPix*Math.cos(theta)*Math.sin(theta)), yPosPix + (int)(lengthFInPix*Math.cos(theta)*Math.cos(theta)));

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(width/2 - 3, height/10 - 3, 6, 6);
    g.drawLine(width/2, height/10, xPosPix, yPosPix);
    g.fillOval(xPosPix - 4, yPosPix - 4, 8, 8);

    g.drawString("T = " + df.format(currentT), 25, 25);

    return g;

}

public void RungeKutta(double theta, double omega){

    a = omegaDot(theta);
    b = omegaDot(theta + 0.5 * h * a);
    c = omegaDot(theta + 0.5 * h * b);
    d = omegaDot(theta + h * c);

    omega = omega + (h / 6) * (a + 2 * b + 2 * c + d);

    a = thetaDot(omega);
    b = thetaDot(omega + 0.5 * h * a);
    c = thetaDot(omega + 0.5 * h * b);
    d = thetaDot(omega + h * c);

    theta = theta + (h / 6) * (a + 2 * b + 2 * c + d);

    this.theta = theta;
    this.omega = omega;

}

public double omegaDot(double theta){

    return -(g / length) * Math.sin(theta);

}

public double thetaDot(double omega){

    return omega;

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Runge-Kutta implementation is correctly taken from the scalar case. However, coupled systems have to be treated as vector-valued ODE, the state of the next stage vector depends on **all** the slopes of the previous stage. You can not separate the updates of the components of the state vector as you tried.

Correct is

```
aomega = omegaDot(theta);
atheta = thetaDot(omega);
bomega = omegaDot(theta + 0.5 * h * atheta);
btheta = thetaDot(omega + 0.5 * h * aomega);
comega = omegaDot(theta + 0.5 * h * btheta);
ctheta = thetaDot(omega + 0.5 * h * bomega);
domega = omegaDot(theta + h * ctheta);
dtheta = thetaDot(omega + h * comega);

omega = omega + (h / 6) * (aomega + 2 * bomega + 2 * comega + domega);
theta = theta + (h / 6) * (atheta + 2 * btheta + 2 * ctheta + dtheta);
```

Note how intertwined the slope computations are.

---

One energy function for the pendulum is
$$
E(θ,ω)=\frac12ω^2 + \frac{g}{L} (1-\cosθ)
$$
At the high point the angular velocity is zero, so $E(θ_H,0)=\frac{g}{L} (1-\cosθ_H)$. At the low point the angle is zero, thus the angular velocity there can be determined from $E(0,ω_L)=\frac12ω_L^2$. The energy is constant, thus
$$
ω_L=\sqrt{2\frac{g}{L} (1-\cosθ_H)}=2\sin(θ_H/2)\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about how to introduce a maximum angle for the pendulum? My current way (setting the maximum angle as the initial one) isn't working. Thanks again, this forum is very helpful!

Comment: Set the initial omega to $0$. Then `theta_0` is the maximal angle.