# Runge-Kutta 4 in polar coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, physics, mathematical-physics, runge-kutta-methods

How is the Runge-Kutta method implemented on this differential equation:

$$ \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt} = -\frac{g}{l} \theta $$

(pendulum motion) which is in polar coordinates?

Let: $c = \frac{g}{l}$

So the first step is:

$$a1 = y_2 dt $$
$$b1 = -c y_1 dt $$

Is this correct?
How do I continue from here?

Comment: It does not matter what type of coordinates you use when applying RK, only the form of the equation. First write the equation as a coupled system of first order equations. Taking $y_1=\theta$ and $y_2 = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ the system can be written $\pmatrix{\frac{dy_1}{dt}\\ \frac{dy_2}{dt}} = \pmatrix{y_2\\-\frac{g}{l}y_1}$. This equation is now on the standard form $\frac{d\vec{y}}{dt} = \vec{f}(\vec{y})$ and you can apply the standard Runge-Kutta.

Comment: @Winther I have updated my answer, could you have a look?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with these three equations. Some words might help. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) for how to apply the RK method.

Comment: @Winther I have already looked at that page, but because I have a vector equation I get cofused. I have edited the question :)

Comment: For a similar problem see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633224/numerically-solving-the-equation-of-a-simple-pendulum-with-runge-kutta with code and corrections.

Comment: The equation is exactly the same when $y$ is a vector: it applies for each of the components of the vector. For example the equation $y_{n+1} = y_n + h f(t_n, y_n)$ becomes  $y_{n+1}^{(i)} = y_n^{(i)} + hf^{(i)}(t_n, \vec{y}_n)$ where $(i)$ denoted the $i$'th component of the vector.